# In a pandas dataframe with a categorical column, extrapolate value of another column across categories

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
     id  cat  flag  value
 0    1    A     1     V1
 1    2    B     1     V2
 2    3    A     0    NaN
 3    4    A     1     V3
 4    5    B     0    NaN
 5    6    C     0    NaN
 6    7    A     0    NaN
 7    8    C     1     V4
 8    9    D     0    NaN
 9   10    E     0    NaN
10   11    D     0    NaN
```

I want to extrapolate the `value` values across the same category wherever a non-null value in that category already exists. Details:

- `flag = 1` for a row means that some `value` will be assigned to that `id`. `flag = 0` means no value is assigned
- If there's a category (like `D` in above e.g.) that has no `id`s with a value assigned to it, then no extrapolation is done for that category (i.e. category `D` rows are left alone)
- For a category (e.g. `B`) with an assigned value, that same value is assigned to all rows for that category (e.g. `V2` is assigned to `id = 5` and `V4` is assigned to `id = 6`)
- If a category has multiple values assigned to it (e.g. category `A` is assigned `V1` for `id = 1` and `V3` for `id = 4`), then those rows are left alone, but all the `A` category rows with no values are to be assigned `V1` (the first value found for category `A`)

The intended output looks like this:

```
     id  cat  flag  value
 0    1    A     1     V1
 1    2    B     1     V2
 2    3    A     1     V1
 3    4    A     1     V3
 4    5    B     1     V2
 5    6    C     1     V4
 6    7    A     1     V1
 7    8    C     1     V4
 8    9    D     0    NaN
 9   10    E     0    NaN
10   11    D     0    NaN
```

I have already worked to generate the category column and to populate the flag column via groupby, but I'm at a loss on how to do this extrapolation bit. Would really appreciate help!

Comment: How is value chosen? When is it V1 vs V2? Is it just order of appearance? If so then how could you ever get V1 and V3 for A?

Comment: @noah: Yeah you can choose it in order of appearance. Actually any tiebreak rule will do - first, last, random - whatever

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Get the first non-null value for each category
x = df.dropna(subset=['value']).groupby('cat')['value'].first()

# Map all values to the first non-null according to their category
y = df['cat'].map(x)

# Blend the existing values with the mappings
df['value'] = df['value'].combine_first(y)
```